# Должен ли Settings сохранять значения после закрытия приложения?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick

Здравствуйте.

Как я понял Settings на то и создан, чтобы хранить настройки даже после закрытия и открытия приложения. Но у меня почему то после повторного открытия приложения значения не восстанавливаются. Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно использовать его, чтобы сохраняло?

кусок кода:

```
    ApplicationWindow {
        id: windowRoot
        visible: true
        width: 600
        height: 700
        title: qsTr("Hello World")


        Settings {
            id: settings
            property int q: settings.q ? "11" : "22"
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                console.log("q = " + settings.q)
                settings.q++
            }
        }
```

вот такой вариант тоже не сохраняет при перезапуске

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: windowRoot
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 700
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    property int testQ: settings.q

    Settings {
        id: settings
        property int q
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            if (!testQ)
                testQ = 1
            console.log("testQ = " + testQ)
            testQ++
        }
    }

    Component.onDestruction: {
        settings.q = testQ
        console.log("q = " + settings.q)
    }
```

Comment: У Вас в коде свойство, которое зависит от себя самого; не могу сказать точно, к чему это приводит, но поведение явно будет странным.

Comment: исправил, смотреть главное сообщение

Answer (score 1):

Решение:
в main.cpp добавить

```
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    app.setOrganizationName("test");
    app.setOrganizationDomain("test");
    app.setApplicationName("test");
```